# (Setup & Deployment) Create a folder & rename destination folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-deployment

I've been using Visual Studio's Setup & Deployment Project to create an installer for a windows service and what i need is to create a folder within the application folder when the installer is run. How would i go about doing this?
I tried adding a folder to the Application Folder in the File System on Target Machine bar, but that's not working.

Also is there a way to specify what the name of the application folder will be?
Right now i have a solution named Tracker.Import.Service and the output folder the install creates is Tracker.Import.Service.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to Jeff's response above, an empty sub-folder will be created if you set the [AlwaysCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1t11k72.aspx) flag for the directory to **true** via the properties panel (it is false by default).

Answer (score 1):

Did you put anything in the sub-folder you created in the Application Folder?  Try adding a target text file to the sub-folder.

If the sub-folder is empty it will not be created.  The installer project will not detect any dependencies on it and will not add it the installer package.

You can set a default for the Application Directory by

- Viewing "Target System on Local Machine"
- right clicking on "Application Folder" and selecting properties.
- Set the value of DefaultLocation to the directory where you want the application installed.